# How to determine currency symbol position for a culture

Tags: c#, localization, currency

I am trying to determine whether the currency symbol for a given culture should appear at the beginning or end of the value. I have not been able to find this bit of information in the .Net CultureInfo, so I thought I'd try a hack:

```
var cultures = new[] {"en-US", "ar-SA", "as-IN", "tr-TR"};
foreach ( var culture in cultures ) {
    var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture( culture );

    var currencyValue = 1.234.ToString( "C", cultureInfo );

    var rtl = cultureInfo.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;

    var symbolAtBeginning = currencyValue.StartsWith( cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, false, cultureInfo );
}
```

Alas, this method works only sometimes; in the example above, it works for "en-US" but not the rest of the cultures. At first I thought it was because some cultures read text right-to-left, and the "start" would be the right side, but that explanation did not prove out.

Does anyone see the flaw in my code, or preferably, have a better method for determining the currency symbol position?

Comment: Pre-Euro, the currency symbol for the Portuguese escudo ($) was positioned in place of the decimal point (123$45 means 123.45 ESC).  Not sure if any current currencies have this characteristic.  In this case, I guess NumberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol would be an empty string, so not useable to determine its position, and NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator would be "$".

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern.aspx) class to determine that information. You can read the [CurrencyPositive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern.aspx) property for positive values and it will return an `int` repesenting the position. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern.aspx):

```
0  $n

1  n$

2  $ n

3  n $
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`CurrencyPositivePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of the `NumberFormat` property of the culture to get the  information. The major pitfall is that there are cultures which text is written in right-to-left (RTL) order. Then you have to reverse the logic.

I have created this extension method.

```
public static class CultureInfoExtensions
{
    public static bool StartsWithCurrencySymbol(this CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool startsWithCurrencySymbol = 
            culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern == 0 ||
            culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern == 2;
        return culture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft ? !startsWithCurrencySymbol : startsWithCurrencySymbol;
    }
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .Where(c => !c.IsNeutralCulture);
foreach (var ci in cultures)
{
    var currencyValue = 1.234.ToString("C", ci);
    if (ci.StartsWithCurrencySymbol())
        Console.WriteLine("Culture: {0} RTLF? {1} Format: {2}",
            ci, ci.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft, currencyValue);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/kNh6un)

[**MSDN**:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
Value    Associated pattern
0                $n
1                n$
2                $ n
3                n $
```

Comment: I'm afraid this method doesn't work for ar-SA in my example, and in your demo output (http://ideone.com/yldaJ1), several other cultures don't work either...

Comment: @Darryl: I must admit that i don't understand following link 100%, however, microsoft tells that in "ar-EG" (same as "ar-SA") _"the currency symbol appears on the left side of the number"_ even if my code tells something different (and even ms output). Maybe you understand how that is meant: http://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/msdn/arabicsupp.aspx (search for _"Formatting Numeric Data for a Specific Arabic Culture"_)

Comment: Tim, thanks for the help. That link seems to show an example and then contradict it and say that it works incorrectly and you should use a workaround (setting the CultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern). I did find support for the assertion that Arabic currency symbols go on the left side here: http://tinyurl.com/pwxpmhn. However, if both of these are right, it means that Excel is wrong, as if you format a cell as currency and specify ar-SA, it puts the currency symbol on the right. Completely confused now.

Comment: I assume that the reason for this is that Arabic text has right-to-left (RTL) order. However, not sure how you should handle that case.

Comment: You have to combine my approach with the CultureInfo.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft property. If that is true you have to use the logical negation operator to reverse the logic.

Comment: Reviewing the behavior for all 210 cultures using the CurrencyPositivePattern method, checking RTL does not quite do it. Comparing against the formatted result using the "C" format, for some the symbol is found correctly at the beginning (ug-CN, he-IL, vr-PK) or end (dv-MV) BUT are RTL, which means negating would result in the wrong answer. Several (mostly Arabic; ar-SA, etc) are found incorrectly at the beginning BUT are RTL, which means negating would result in the correct answer. So no silver bullet, but the corner cases are few, so perhaps I could just code exceptions for them.

Answer (score 0):

> Alas, this method works only sometimes; in the example above, it works for "en-US" but not the rest of the cultures.

Why do you say that?  As far as I can see, it works for all cultures.  Adding a bit of tracing, I get the following, which is exactly what I'd expect: symbolAtBeginning is true IFF the currency symbol is on the left for LTR cultures and on the right for RTL cultures.

```
culture:en-US currencyValue:$1.23 rtl:False symbolAtBeginning:True
culture:ar-SA currencyValue:ر.س.‏ 1.23 rtl:True symbolAtBeginning:True
culture:as-IN currencyValue:₹ 1.23 rtl:False symbolAtBeginning:True
culture:tr-TR currencyValue:1,23 ₺ rtl:False symbolAtBeginning:False
```

Comment: In my testing, the as-IN currencyValue is "1.23₹", which fails. Also, tr-TR has symbolAtBeginning:True which also fails.

Comment: My test was on Windows 8, what OS are you using?